# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string

Tags: php, oop

I have some problem and error after update my PHP version to 7 ... some errors like this ->

> error -> ( Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   prepare() on string );

**//This Is My Code**

```
<?php

/** config **/

class dbConnection
{
    protected $db_conn;

    public $db_host = 'localhost';
    public $db_name = 'test';

    public $db_user = 'root';
    public $db_pass = '';

    function connection()
    {
        try{
            $a = $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name;charset=utf8",$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
            return $this->db_conn;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

?>

```
<?php

    /**  Class Users **/

    class ManageUser{

        public $link;

        function __construct(){
            $dbconnection = new dbConnection();
            $this->link = $dbconnection->connection();
            return $this->link;
        }

        //Get user
        function GetUsersInfo($username)
        {
            $query = $this->link->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tbl_administrator` WHERE username = '$username' ");
            $query->bindValue(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->execute();
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }

    }

?>

<?php

    $n = new ManageUser();
    $a = $n->GetUsersInfo('a');
    print_r($a);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, that you have an `exception` and that's why `$this->link` is a `string` not an `object`. Try to debug this exception.

```
    catch(PDOException $e){
        var_dump($e);
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
```

And please don't catch exception to return an exception message from object method. **Always try to handle an exception and re-throw it**. Handle exception at the end of script flow.

```
    catch(PDOException $e){
        // log exception message, ...
        throw $e;
    }
```

**Don't design method which return object(dbconnection) or string(exception message) It's a fatal design.**